# Javascript Addition Program

Tags: javascript, web, browser, addition

This is a javascript program for adding two numbers but the problem is the code is too big and  everytime I need to change the number to the integer by parseInt so if I need to add more numbers the code will become more lengthy. How can I make it more simple?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>adding</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x; 
var y;
var z;
var n;
var result;

x=prompt("1st number");
y=prompt("2nd number");
z=parseInt(x);
n=parseInt(y);
result= n + z;
alert(result);
</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

`

Comment: learn about [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: example https://jsfiddle.net/yy880o71/

Comment: `alert(Array.from(Array(3)).map(prompt.bind(window, "Enter Number")).map(Number).filter(Number).reduce((a,b)=>a+b));` you can change `3` to how ever many terms you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a js function:

```
function addNumbers(arr) {
var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    result += parseInt(arr[i]);
  }
  return result;
}

function evaluate(){
  var numberArray = document.selectElementById("numbers").value.split(",");
  alert(addNumbers(numberArray));
}
```

and add a html input field:

```
<input id="numbers"/>
<button onclick="evaluate()"></button>
```

this will add all numbers you typed into the input field (comma seperated)

**note:**

this will only work with valid inputs, i.e.:

`1,2,4,-8` would work
`1 2,5,2`  would not work
`e,2,3`  would not work

Comment: tried but not working.In the input field I typed 4,5 and after clicking the button nothing happens :(

Comment: add.html:30 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': 2 arguments required, but only 0 present.onclick @ add.html:30 this error

Comment: so post your current code - the error tells you, that you call a function with not enough parameters. But my `evaluate()` does not receive any parameters, so the error must be at your place

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>add</title>
</head>
<body>




<script type="text/javascript">

function addNumbers(arr) {
var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    result += parseInt(arr[i]);
  }
  return result;
}

function evaluate(){
  var numberArray = document.selectElementById("numbers").value.split(",");
  alert(addNumbers(numberArray));
}

</script>

<input id="numbers"/>
<button onclick="evaluate()"></button>



</body>

</html>